# How to dynamically add data to an AlertDialog using a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a function, the user adds text, the following dynamic add a data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyiJ8.png)
In fact, it is not the same as imagined, I imagine clicking upload file, and there is no blank in the middle of the name, every time you add a file, the middle will squeeze out a position

my code

```
  void _showEditDialog() async {
    StateSetter _setState;
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
        return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          title: const Text('添加知识库'),
          content: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                _setState = setState;
                return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "名字"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Scaffold(
                      body: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: fileName.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Text(fileName[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),);
                          }
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: isButtonDisabled ? null : () => {_openFile1(_setState)},
                    child: const Row(
                      children: [
                        Text("点击上传文件",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // 设置字体粗细
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                 //       Spacer(), // 添加这个以增加间距

                        Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print(controller.text);
                for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                  File file = fileList[i];
                  var md51 = md5.convert(await file.readAsBytes());
                  ApiService.uploadFileWithParams(
                      file.path, controller.text, md51.toString());
                }
                _showToast("文件上传完成");
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('确认'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // 取消
              },
              child: const Text('取消'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

My listView must use a Scaffold and must give a height

Otherwise, an exception will occur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJhip.png)

I tested a lot of listview usage and found that it works only if I wrap it around a scaffold and give it a height, but I don't want to give it a default height and the scaffold's background color isn't right.